# ASP.NET Core strange alphanumeric character

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

Is anyone able to tell me what are these alphanumeric characters that are in HTML tags when debugging an ASP.NET Core web application?

Thank you very much!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: See [ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

This feature called `ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation`, is supported starting from ASP.NET Core 5.0 and according the documentation ([ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0)) used to isolate CSS styles to individual pages, views, and components to reduce or avoid:

> - Dependencies on global styles that can be challenging to maintain.
> - Style conflicts in nested content.

From the documentation:

*CSS isolation occurs at **build time**. Blazor rewrites CSS selectors to match markup rendered by the component. The rewritten CSS styles are **bundled** and produced as a static asset.*

*Within the bundled file, each component is associated with a scope identifier. For each styled component, an HTML attribute is appended with the format `b-{STRING}`, where the `{STRING}` placeholder is a **ten-character string generated by the framework** by default. The identifier is unique for each app. [But the scope identifier format can be customized, by updating the project file to a desired pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-scope-identifier-format).*

*Scoped CSS only applies to HTML elements and not to Razor components or Tag Helpers, including elements with a Tag Helper applied, such as `<input asp-for="..." />`.**

*To disable CSS isolation for a project set the  property to false in the app's project file:*

```
<ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>
```